# Mongo db vs (My Sql OR Sql Server) for a classified application

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mongodb, nosql

We have a classified website. I read few things but still not got a solid reason to choose between these.

My requirement is to just create user, listing and manage these. These are paid listings so monetary transactions would be there.

As per my research (https://www.mongodb.com/compare/mongodb-mysql) I found that mongo db has edge over other options except for complex transactions. What are complex transaction in this context? Any specific examples?

What factors should I consider before choosing one. I have experience with My SQL and Entity framework so its more appealing to me now but are these really bad for scaling when compared with mongo?

Feel free to suggest any other good performance option apart from these choices.

Comment: This question belongs on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a vast difference between mongoDB and MySQL or SQL Server.
MongoDB is a NoSQL database meaning it is schemaless and doesnot follow CODD Rules of RDBMS whereas MySQL/SQL Server is relational Database.

Each are meant for different use cases. As per [mongoDB doc](https://www.mongodb.com/compare/mongodb-mysql)

> **Why use MongoDB instead of MySQL?**
>   Organizations of all sizes are adopting MongoDB because it enables them to build applications faster, handle highly diverse data types, and manage applications more efficiently at scale.
>
> Development is simplified as MongoDB documents map naturally to modern, object-oriented programming languages. Using MongoDB removes the complex object-relational mapping (ORM) layer that translates objects in code to relational tables.
>
> MongoDB’s flexible data model also means that your database schema can evolve with business requirements. For example, the ALTER TABLE command required to add a single, new field to Craiglist’s MySQL database would take months to execute. The Craigslist team migrated to MongoDB because it can accommodate changes to the data model without such costly schema migrations.
>
> MongoDB can also be scaled within and across multiple distributed data centers, providing new levels of availability and scalability previously unachievable with relational databases like MySQL. As your deployments grow in terms of data volume and throughput, MongoDB scales easily with no downtime, and without changing your application. In contrast, to achieve scale with MySQL often requires significant, custom engineering work.
>
> **What are common use cases for MongoDB?**
>   MongoDB is a general purpose database that is used for a variety of use cases. The most common use cases for MongoDB include Single View, Internet of Things, Mobile, Real-Time Analytics, Personalization, Catalog, and Content Management.
>
> **When would MySQL be a better fit?**
>   While most modern applications require a flexible, scalable system like MongoDB, there are use cases for which a relational database like MySQL would be better suited. Applications that require complex, multi-row transactions (e.g., a double-entry bookkeeping system) would be good examples. MongoDB is not a drop-in replacement for legacy applications built around the relational data model and SQL.
>
> A concrete example would be the booking engine behind a travel reservation system, which also typically involves complex transactions. While the core booking engine might run on MySQL, those parts of the app that engage with users – serving up content, integrating with social networks, managing sessions – would be better placed in MongoDB

As there is no concept of join in MongoDB so if you want to store data, either you have to create a hack to store data in two table(although it is expensive cal to join in MongoDB) or you have to store data as a single document,, making your document too complex.In these cases MySQL has upperhand.

Comment: How are we defining complexity here i.e. railway booking system? Why can't it be done with No sql? 

Can something like Air bnb which too is some reservation system be done with no sql or would it require sql databases. If yes, can you give a reason for that?